# Convert a coordinate in string in int array

Tags: javascript

I'm beginner in javascript and I have a problem to convert a string to a array of int.
I find for this case

```
var string = "[1,2,3,4]";
```

but not for this one:

```
var string = "[[1,2],[1,2]]";
```

And have the same syntax

```
var result = [[1,2],[1,2]];

result = [[1,2],[1,2]];
```

Comment: `JSON.parse` should handle both.  Perhaps the question could be clearer.  What is your expected output for `var string = "[1,2,3,4]";`

Comment: I have a string : var string = "[[1,2],[1,2]]"; and I would this result : result = [[1,2],[1,2]];

Comment: `JSON.parse` will convert that to the expected output.

Comment: otherwise use `eval("[[1,2],[1,2]]")`

Comment: Generally you should never use `eval` unless you have to dynamically write actual javascript code.  Using it to parse JSON data is unsafe and highly discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var 
  str = '[[1,2],[3,4]]',
  result;

result = JSON.parse(str);

result[0] // [1, 2]
result[1] // [3, 4]

result[0][0] // 1
result[1][1] // 4
```

[Read more about JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

I don't recommend you to use `eval()` function.

> [**Object-Oriented JavaScript - Second Edition**](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/object-oriented-javascript-second-edition): eval() can be useful
>   sometimes, but should be avoided if there are other options. Most of
>   the time there are alternatives, and in most cases the alternatives
>   are more elegant and easier to write and maintain. "**Eval is evil**" is a
>   mantra you can often hear from seasoned JavaScript programmers. The
>   drawbacks of using eval() are:
>
> **Security** – JavaScript is powerful, which also means it can cause damage. If you don't trust the source of the input you pass to eval(),
>   just don't use it.
>
> **Performance** – It's slower to evaluate "live" code than to have the code directly in the script.